# How to set database connection name when connecting to Sybase with Websphere datasource

Tags: java, spring, websphere, sybase

We have created a web application which uses datasource defined in Websphere to connect to Sybase database. Since we have defined many jobs within the application, we need to monitor how many connections each job uses.

When we check the sybase processes in database when the jobs were running, `SELECT * FROM master..sysprocesses`
all the connections have `program_name` column value as `com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool`

Is there anyway that we can set/change this value(like the `jobname` may be) while making connections to database so that we would know what connections are used by what jobs?

```
Database - Sybase ASE 15.7
App Server - Websphere 7
Application Runtime - Java 6
Application Framework - Spring 3
Database Driver - Jconnect 7
```

will the `setClientInfo` method of Connection class can be of any help to set the programe_name value?

Comment: Give eaach job its own thread pool and let that be entered into the table.

Comment: @duffymo that is not possible since all jobs(Quartz) run within the same application and share common thread pool

Comment: I'm suggesting that they shouldn't share a common thread pool.  Or they shouldn't be sharing a database.  Or they shouldn't be sharing a connection pool.  Can you set up separate connection pools for each app?

Comment: in past we had different db2 datasourace for same db, in order to throttle/debug the connection usage, this sounds similar

Comment: We have some 30-40 jobs defined in quartz and can also be added dynamically from the application UI. we cannot have separate datasources for each jobs